# Image upload functionality- xpath issues

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

We have a upload functionality where we can upload .csv files and I am trying to automate this using selenium webdriver.

Here is the xpaths i have used,but none of them are working.

1. //span[contains(text(),'click here to browse')]
2. //input[@type='file']

Any suggestions for this type of functionality

[image: Here is the snippet]

[Below is the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bF6K.png)

Comment: getting any exception ?

Comment: no exception. Error says cant find the element with the above xpaths mentioned.

Comment: can you update UI snap in question ? or the website link ?

Comment: Here is the UI of the element. Need to click on "Click here to browse" and then upload a file.

Comment: You have to use AutoIT to upload file in these kind of browse option. if you are trying simple sendkeys then it wont work

Comment: but i was thinking this woud work "driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys("D:\\Documentatio‌​n\\uploadFile.xls")";